# The truth value of $(P):(\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}) (\forall y\in \mathbb{Q}) : my\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

**Determine the truth value of the following statement:**
$$(P):(\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}) (\forall y\in \mathbb{Q}) : my\in\mathbb{N}$$

**my attempt:**

P is false, because
suppose that exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{-}$ such that:
$$(\forall y\in \mathbb{Q}) : my\in\mathbb{N} $$
let's take for example: $y=\frac{m}{m}\in\mathbb{Q}$ we got :
$$m.y=m.\frac{m}{m}=m\notin \mathbb{N} $$ since $m\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{-}$.
Therefore, the statement (P) is false.

Comment: Do you include $0\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,... \}$

Comment: @Donfreecss "*suppose that exists $m \in \mathbb Z^∗_-$*" $\;-\;$ The statement is about $\,m \in \mathbb Z\,$, so proving that there is no such $\,m \in \mathbb Z^*_-\,$ does not contradict it.

Comment: @thank you for such good explanation

Comment: I see that you have not accepted any answers. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: no I just want to be sure that I have no more clarification Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you include $0\in\Bbb N$, $(P)$ is true because we have $\Bbb Z\ni 0=0y\in\Bbb N$ for all $y\in\Bbb Q$.

---

Your proof is wrong even if $0\notin\Bbb N$, since you only exclude negative $m$.

---

To prove $(P)$ is false when $0\notin\Bbb N$, let $y=0$.

Comment: could you elaborate more, does my proof wrong does the statement true ... Thanks

Comment: What is there to elaborate, @Donfreecss? Just let $m=0$. Your proof is wrong, necessarily.

Comment: Please, could you add the case, where $0\notin \mathbb{N}$ is my proof would be correct in that case, Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer, @Donfreecss.

Comment: Pleas, one more question: could you give the truth value of its negation: $(\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}) (\exists y\in \mathbb{Q}) : my\notin\mathbb{N}$. False, because

Comment: Just let $y=0$.